# How to remove a line and replace with another line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an application with Pyqt5 (QT). The application do the Password Manager tasks.

I have a text file that names and passwords stored in it (encrypted).

One section of app has a tool that user can change the password from entering the name. (If you don't understand look at the picture.)

[image: screenshot]

My text file is like this :

```
newname1|password1
newname2|password2
...
```

As you noticed, after `"|"` is the password. How can I find `newname2` and just replace the password section from new password field, or remove the line and replace with a new one (for example: `newname2|newpassword`)?

Also I have to say that I know how to fetch data from inputs, I just want to know how to do it in python code.

Comment: I removed `PyQt` tag since the problem is about reading the data from the text file, and it doesn't actually have anything to do with `PyQt`. You can still edit the answer and add that tag if you really think that is going to help you.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Ok thanks, but can't you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
out = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
name, newPass = 'newname2', 'NewPassword2'
for idx,line in enumerate(out):
    if line.startswith(name+'|'):
        out[idx] = f'{name}|{newPass}'
        fBuffer = open('file.txt', 'w')
        fBuffer.writelines(out)
        break
else:
    print('User Name not found')
```

You can take the `name`, and `newPass` from PyQt UI's lineEdit, read the file which has the name and the passwords stored, then iterate through these lines and check if `newname2|` is there in the file, if so, update the list. Then write back to the file, and exit the loop immediately.

Comment: prefect! it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = '''
a|b
c|d
'''

username = 'a'
new_password = '123'


import re

new_string = re.sub(f'(?<=^{username}\|).*', new_password , string,  flags=re.M)

print(new_string) # This string can be written back to the file.
```

**Note:** Not efficient but works.